# How to reset the tabs inside <pre><code>?

Tags: html, css, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I have a div structure that is multiple levels deep where I'd like to utilize `<pre>` and `<code>`, to use some syntax.

Essentially, it looks similar to this:

```
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
     <div class="three">
        <pre class="syntax-hl">
          <code>
            //my JS code here
          </code>
        </pre>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I am seeing is that when it renders, it keeps all of its tabs and moves the entire code block (4) tabs in, instead of the expected outcome of only 1.

I've tried applying different `white-space` settings, which sort of work in the fact that they trim the leading space, however when they remove the leading whitespace, they also lose all of their tabs.

Has anyone encountered this, or know of a way to fix it?

Here is a pretty barebones example you can play with that should explain what I'm trying to fix.
https://jsfiddle.net/d3e26p0w/

Comment: no wrap for pre and margin-left for code will work- are you looking for something like this- https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/WqExjr

Comment: @NagaSaiA it's close, but i'm basically looking for the code tag to start right where the pre tag is starting, and I need to have wrap on to handle indenting

Comment: The formal recommendation is to use `<pre><code>` on one line, without indenting the `<code>`. That will save you one level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to move the `border` to the `pre`, then you are free to give the `code` a negative left margin.

```css
pre.syntax-hl {
  margin: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

pre.syntax-hl > code {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: -6ch;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    <div class="three">
      <pre class="syntax-hl"><code>
        request.onload = function() {
          if (request.status >= 200 &amp;&amp; request.status &lt; 400) { 
            // Success! var data=JSON.parse(request.responseText); 
          } else { 
            //We reached our target server, but it returned an error 
          }
        }; 
      </code></pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But to answer your question, no, the indentation inside the `<code>` block does not start at the indentation of the parent; in CSS there is no way you can make the indentation depend on where the `<pre>` is on the line in the source.

Comment: Yeah I ended up trimming the leading space serverside, so that solved my issue. However your explanation is complete enough for future users, that I'll mark it as accepted. Thank you!